# Which device/partition should I select to install bootloader (Boot mode: UEFI, storage GPT with NMVe controller)? Ubuntu 20.04+W11

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I am installing in dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11, my BIOS mode is UEFI and the storage type GPT, with storage controller NVMe. I am selecting the device for boot loader installation and I do not know which one to select.

1. Some guides suggest to select the whole disk /dev/nmve0n1, but I read that this way I would overwrite the beginning of the disk and this might create problems to Windows;
2. Some guides suggest to select the windows EFI partition which is /dev/nmve0n1p1, which would overwrite Windows bootloader;
3. Other suggest to use root partition ("/") in which the ubuntu boot folder will be installed, saying this would not alter windows, but then one must manually add Ubuntu to the bootloader, and I didn't get if I can do it in boot mode UEFI or not.
4. Some guides suggest to create a specific EFI partition of 500 MB, but they say also it is not recommended to have two EFI partitions on the same disk.

Which is the best way to go on?
Thanks

Comment: Whatever you select, it will be ignored.  See bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  There should only be one EFI per device.  The default will write the ubuntu bootloaders into ...EFI/ubuntu, so no conflicts with Windows, but the ubuntu bootloaders will also be written into ...EFI/boot (as bootx64.efi) for the device boot.

Comment: According to this link (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI ) you may not have configured your install media for UEFI boot. `Note that in a UEFI-mode installation, Ubuntu will not ask you where to install the boot loader. If it does, or if it complains about the lack of a BIOS Boot Partition, you've probably accidentally booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.`

Comment: @ubfan Sorry, I did not get what you mean. Could you please clarify?
This bug thread seems to tackle the case of two different drives, while I just have a single drive which is partitioned. Where will the EFI/ubuntu be? How are there no conflicts with windows? Thank you for your help

Comment: @PonJar I am 100% sure I configured my install media for partition scheme GPT and Target UEFI (non-CSM).
It asks because during installation I am selecting "Something else" and manually creating/selecting partition (to create the "/" and the "swap" one), and not the automatic "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows boot manager".

Comment: The EFI partition starts with the EFI directory, so if you mount it at /mnt, the Ubuntu bootloaders are in /mnt/EFI/ubuntu (normally a running Ubuntu system mounts the EFI partition at /boot/efi). The Windows bootloaders are under .../EFI/Microsoft/Boot, so no conflicts with the Ubuntu bootloaders. The  Ubuntu bootloaders takeup an additional 5MB, so there's probably lots of room on the existing EFI partition.

Comment: Then, this mean that when I install Ubuntu, am I supposed to leave the default option (here, the n. 1.), and then Ubuntu will find the right partition to install the bootloader, or should I suggest it to install in the same partition as Windows Boot Manager (option n. 2?) ?
I quitted the installation before because I was not sure of what I was doing, so I am still open to suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: If choosing where to install boot loader, you always select a drive, not a partition. If a BIOS install (which you should not be doing) will break Windows if grub installed to any NTFS partition. As ubfan1 says, it does not matter with Ubiquity installer in UEFI mode, it always installs to first drive's ESP. Major work arounds required if you really want boot loader on external drive or any second drive.

Comment: With UEFI and dual boot there are multiple entries in the EFI partition, some for Windows, some for Linux. Those for Linux will not overwrite those for Windows